# Required Power Supply Driver for Peltier Module TEC12715?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, peltier, power-consumption

I am making a Mini-Air conditioner based on Peltier TEC12715. I'm going to use 10 peltier elements for better cooling. 1 peltier module requires: Umax(V):15.4 Imax(A):15 Max power consumption (watt):231 Watt . How much power supply is required to run all 10 Peltier Module. Which **Power supply driver(AC to DC)** should i pick?

Comment: First, you want to look at How to driver a Peltier element : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28634/how-to-drive-a-peltier-element

Comment: With that amount of power it makes much more sense to use a compressor.