# how to control peltier element with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, peltier

I need a little help from experienced people. 
I want to control a Peltier element with a microcontroller, with PWM. May? 
The peltier element has the following parameters: Imax=8.3 A, Vmax=3.8V.Ok... 
I have a 12 volt source for example, and the circuit need to be able to support 8 amps? What circuit can i use to reduce te voltage, And that circuit will support 8 amp  ?

Comment: A link to the peltier element data sheet is needed.

Comment: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1955497.pdf?_ga=2.267214284.313047213.1531319251-2054950381.1531319251

Comment: Please, edit your post to include the link. This will improve your answer. Comments are only a temporary mean of communications here. They may not last. And the question needs to stand on its own with all the needed information.

Comment: BTW, all of your concerns are covered [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28634/how-to-drive-a-peltier-element). The only detail missing is calculations for your specific case. TL;DR: you cannot use PWM directly to drive a Peltier cell, you need to convert it to a proportional DC level to avoid damaging the cell.